# set margin to the 1st row of gridview

Tags: android, gridview, toolbar, transparent

I want the gridview to start from under the tablayout(marked red) but be scrollable beneath the transparent toolbar and the tablayout. I tried to set marginTop to the gridview but the gridview stays fixed in that place and doesn't scroll underneath the toolbar and tablayout. Is there any way to set margin to the 1st row of the gridview?

[image]

My XML code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Fragments.CompetitionFragment">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/statusBarColor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comptoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@color/statusBarColor"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/glostarslogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Competition"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/MyTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fabs" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your XML layout code?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 I have edited my question and added the code.

Comment: Try putting `ViewPager` and `AppBarLayout` in a LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 that wont serve my purpose. Your suggestion will put the two views one under another, not underneath them. I want the AppBarLayout and the ViewPager to overlap.

Comment: Then try using FrameLayout.

Comment: That disables the collapsing of the toolbar. I want to know if is there any way to set margin to the 1st row of the gridlayout.

Comment: You can set padding for the Gridview. Will that serve your purpose?